# Pressing "Enter" to start Java program again

Tags: java

I'm very new to Java and I am not very sure about it just yet. My friend and I have been playing around with a program where we input text and it gives us the frequency and the word count of the sentence.

When it comes to the end of the program, we would like to add in an option to press "Enter" to start again, but we are not sure what code to write at all and where about in the program it should go.

Any help would be appreciated!

Pastebin Link to our code: http://pastebin.com/6x0qkNt0

Comment: Ok, where do you think you would start? Whats your best guess?

Comment: My advice, start with optimizing your code first. put repeated code in parameterized methods and such, you'll loose half your code (or more) making it a lot easier to read and maintain.

Comment: you should put some code in your question. dont put a link to your code

Comment: Oh MY! The description of your program does not presage 700 lines of code, more like 70.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to do is to create a loop:

```
String answer = "y";
while(answer.equals("y")){
   runProgram();
   [...]
}
```

Call your existing code inside the `{}` and prompt the user to enter 'y' if he wants to continue using the program instead of the `[...]`. Looking at your code I'd say some cleanup might be a good idea.

Comment: Im not completely sure what you mean, very new to all of this! Where in my code do I place this?

Comment: I assume all that code you pasted is within a `main` method? Try creating another method `runProgram`and put your code in there.

Comment: It is inside a main method yes, but we are struggling with inputting the code you have shown us in the right place. Sorry about this, we are complete amateurs. This is out exact code at the minute: http://pastebin.com/CkE4cAw6

Comment: Put all your code within `private void runProgram(){ ... }` and put the code I posted before into your main. You should read of on methods. I don't think I will have time to give you more detailed instructions, but I think you should learn a bit more about the general principles before proceeding anyways. Good luck!